# Create-React-App - any way to transpile code without ejecting

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, create-react-app, transpiler

I've created an app using create-react-app.

I am using ES5/ES6 features like

```
arrayOfObjects.find(object => object.value == desiredValue);
```

Of course, this won't work in older browsers like IE11. You'll get an error like 'find doesn't exist'.

Is there any way to transpile my code without having to eject?

Comment: So you built an app with CRA and it didn’t translate everything to ES5?

Comment: If the feature doesn't exist in a browser you're targeting, you need to use a polyfill. Just google "array prototype find polyfill" and you should find what you're looking for. [Here's the relevant docs.](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/supported-browsers-features#supported-browsers)

Comment: @AlexGuerra Thanks for the tip, I'll check that out